# Regex lookahead more than one element

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Is it possible to use a lookahead to establish whether one or more characters does/doesn't exist when those characters do not *immediately* follow the lookahead assertion?

e.g.
Given regex similar to this:

```
([abc])([def])([ghi])
```

could I, say, only allow the 'i' in the third group as a match if there was an 'a' in the first group?

Comment: It seems to me what you really want is look-behind, not look-ahead. Are you using pcre/perl RE?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript, but I'm asking purely out of curiosity (I'm not currently trying to solve a problem with it). With JavaScript, lookbehinds are out of the question, but I feel like anything that can be done with a lookbehind could also be done with a lookahead.

Comment: And this is why the regex tag's FAQ says that you always should add a tag for the language you're using the regex with :) And no, you definitely can't do everything a lookbehind can do with lookaheads. Unless you *only* have lookbehinds in your regex - then you can reverse the string *and* the regex to transform the lookbehinds into lookaheads.

Comment: Sorry; added 'javascript' tag. Yep – I've definitely overlooked something with lookbehinds. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind assertion (unless you're targeting JavaScript where they are not supported by the regex engine):

```
([abc])([def])([gh]|(?<=a.)i)
```

Comment: Ah – it's the '.' that's important there, right? Let's say ([def]) was optional – can it be resolved then with capturing groups, somehow?

Comment: @davidpmccormick: Again, that depends on the regex engine. Lookbehinds (if they exist) are fixed-length in some, finite-length in most, and indefinite-lengths in few regex flavors. So, in PHP, you could use `([abc])([def])?([gh]|(?<=a.?)i)`, but not in Python.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'd give you credit, but my feeble reputation won't permit it. Consider yourself credited, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use OR operation use `|`
Like this

```
(asd)|(zxc)|(qwe)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional pattern.

Try this :

```
/((a)|(b|c))([def])(?(2)i|[gh])/
```

(tested with PCRE)